# converting blob image to array to display in the web page in spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

Am trying to display an image for the profile of a customer. and the image is stored in blob type in mysql. am using spring mvc with hibernate. i know that to display an image which is blob type, we have to convert into bytes. i did upto some extent. now am stuck that am not able to display any image.

```
  my controller:
   @RequestMapping(value="/myProfile.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)

  public ModelAndView Profilelist(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap model,Customer        
 customer,Profile profile, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException , 
 Exception{
    //Profile profile = new Profile();

    String customerName = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();

    customer = customerService.getCustomerId(customerName);
    profile = profileService.getBycustomerId(customer);
    System.out.println("cust:  "+ customer);
    System.out.println("profile:  "+ profile);
    logger.error("Viewing Profile" +customerName);
    //Customer customer = new Customer();



    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    /*byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
    String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("profile", base64Encoded);*/
    Blob blob = profile.getContent();
    InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
    System.out.println("id content" +in);
    int n = 0;
    while ((n=in.read(buf))>=0)
    {
       baos.write(buf, 0, n);

    }

    in.close();
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray(); 
    System.out.println("bytes" +bytes);
    byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
    String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    //mav.addObject("content", base64Encoded);
    customer.setEmailId(customerName);
    profile.setCustomer(customer);
    //profile.setContent(blob);
    System.out.println();
    profile = profileService.findProfileById(customer);
    model.addAttribute("content",base64Encoded);

    model.addAttribute("profile", profile);
    mav = new ModelAndView("myProfile");
    return mav;}
```

And in jsp am calling it as

```
       <img  src= "data:image/jpeg;bytes,${profile.content}"/>
```

My jsp is

```
     <form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="profile" action="myProfile.htm"   
             enctype="multipart/form-data">


            <div class="containerdiv" align="center" >

                   <img  src= "data:image/jpeg;bytes,${content}"/>

                   </div>
   </form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Persisting Image Blob object on your database is not a good practice. just persist the filename of your image in db and the image itself to a certain path.

I know that this is not what you asking for but If you know how to upload a photo to a specific directory and since you are using spring You can take it as an alternatives.

why dont you create a Controller to read the image for you. see this:

```
@Controller
public class ImageReadFile{

    // this is for mapping your image related path. 
    @RequestMapping(value="/image/*")
    public void readImage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ServletContext sc = request.getServletContext();

        //here i uploaded my image in this path
        String imagePath = "/home/somefolder/Workspaces/Images/";
        String [] fragmentFilename = request.getServletPath().split("/");

        //Check if image isn't set
        if(fragmentFilename.length <= 2){
            return;
        }

        String filename = fragmentFilename[2];
        String requestedImage = "/"+filename;

        if(filename == null){
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        File image = new File(imagePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedImage, "UTF-8"));

        if(!image.exists()){
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }

        String contentType = sc.getMimeType(image.getName());
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
        Files.copy(image.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

This is how you gonna diplay the image

```
<img alt="${profile.filename}" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/image/${profile.filename}">
```

this is how i display the image in my webapp.

Comment: ok i'll try... if it works for me... am very thankful to you...and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

just use this code in JSP

```
<img alt="img" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${content}"/>
```

there was 'bytes' in `<img tag>` and I'd got same broken icon. Then I use 'base64' in `<img>` tag and its work!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your image still uses blob from profile rather than encoded string. Try using content attribute directly

```
<img  src= "data:image/jpeg;bytes,${content}"/>
```

Comment: thank you for response... i did what you told...still same issue

Comment: am stuck with this from last two days

Comment: just an broken image icon is displayed. but when i open that broken image icon in new tab a big url came but that same broken image is coming.

Answer (score 0):

You have written some wrong code, let me try to correct it,

**Replace**

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
//mav.addObject("content", base64Encoded); 
customer.setEmailId(customerName);
profile.setCustomer(customer);
//profile.setContent(blob); 
System.out.println();
profile = profileService.findProfileById(customer);
model.addAttribute("content",base64Encoded);

model.addAttribute("profile", profile);
mav = new ModelAndView("myProfile");
return mav;}
```

---

**With**

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
customer.setEmailId(customerName);
profile.setCustomer(customer);
profile = profileService.findProfileById(customer);
mav.addObject("content", base64Encoded);
mav.addObject("profile", profile);   
return mav;
}
```

Comment: i did what you suggested.. same issue... just an broken image icon is displayed on a page. but when i open that broken image icon in new tab a big url came but that same broken image is coming. with an message

Comment: "data:image/jpeg;bytes,55SAG3JJJjWSSTP5Co+5dKy0kA/xAiffTjEXr1sD2/swOQzkE8j91ST+taiuIcV9rltosAfH/as/6T/wrDQq+PDApIM+OtNzeVSuXfbeNN+UA+tJLhbgYDL8RHqaZXcPczfdiOZ29OtWmmIsvD7YuuQ+q8lH589PnUXjsGqXSikgzIg7T/xvS3BrwttmcyeszPXypvjmzYlmzSNIKjYbRp0+tbprov8ApHV9n/wkThdp38qFKzMEnl1rla0QiEs4jwp2cQI2oUK8t7OwicDjG9o4Yk6H0g09a9rQoVfIlYkxPEkFe9MeG9JYbGgaKs52G0zYmC0K8S49bt9y0DcunSAJA6kkdKr/ABPtFcxByWhCfygn4jeu4LCXlEW7Rk7s0SfMnl4UAPrl0ALNtw==" because it contains error

Comment: this is comming when i open that broken image icon

Comment: Right, you are getting this as responce as you are sending the same data from the controller.